# Can we create a socket connection over TLS client and TLS protocol for http url in Blackberry?

Tags: ssl, blackberry, java-me, bouncycastle

I am using BouncyCastle library to create a secure connection. But in one of my requirements i have a url starting with "http".

Can i create a socket connection with "http" url using same approach.

Comment: Why would you want to create a socket connection to an web server that expects to process the data in http format?  Are you going to implement your own http protocol handling?

Comment: To me, you haven't answered my questions.  And, also as I understood it, if you are using an http URL, you are expected to communicate with the server using http protocol.  So your response "There are different protocols used in different environment" makes no sense, at least not to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a URL starting with "http:" you don't want SSL, you want plaintext.

If on the other hand your URL starts with "https:" you will automatically get SSL.

Comment: Do you mean I shall skip the TLS protocol and open the stream from Socket connection object only?

Comment: I meant what I said and nothing more. Specifically, I didn't say a single word about Sockets. You gave a URL: the next logical move is 'new URL()', and thine after that is 'openConnection()' etc.